Find $\inf_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{1} (t^3 - a - bt - ct^2)^2 \, dt$
Find $$\inf_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{1} (t^3 - a - bt - ct^2)^2 \, dt.$$
This has to be done using the scalar products and projections. I can see that the scalar product in question is $$b(f,g) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) g(x) \, dx.$$
But I really don't understand how to handle the rest.

What are $f$ and $g$?

What stops you from computing the integral first?

Let $E=\mathbb{R}_3[X]$ equipped with the scalar product : $(P,Q)=\int_0^1P(t)Q(t)\,dt$.
Then $$\displaystyle \inf_{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3}\int_0^1(t^3-a-bt-ct^2)^2\,dt=\inf_{Q\in\mathbb{R}_2[X]} \|X^3-Q\|^2=\|X^3-p_{\mathbb{R}_2[X]}(X^3)\|^2$$ where $p_{\mathbb{R}_2[X]}$ is the orthogonal projection on $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$.
Let $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be such that $p_{\mathbb{R}_2[X]}(X^3)=a+bX+cX^2$. Then $$X^3-(a+bX+cX^2)\perp \mathbb{R}_2[X]$$
In particular $$(X^3-(a+bX+cX^2), 1)=(X^3-(a+bX+cX^2), X)=(X^3-(a+bX+cX^2), X^2)=0$$
But $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
(X^3-(a+bX+cX^2), 1)&=&0\\
(X^3-(a+bX+cX^2), X)&=&0\\
(X^3-(a+bX+cX^2), X^2)&=&0\\
\end{array}\right. \Longleftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
a+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{c}{3}&=&\frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{4}&=&\frac{1}{5}\\
\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{4}+\frac{c}{5}&=&\frac{1}{6}\\
\end{array}\right.\Longleftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
a&=&\frac{1}{20}\\
b&=&-\frac{3}{5}\\
c&=&\frac{3}{2}\\
\end{array}\right.$$
Hence $$\displaystyle\inf_{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3}\int_0^1(t^3-a-bt-ct^2)^2\,dt=\int_0^1\left(t^3-\frac{1}{20}+\frac{3}{5}t-\frac{3}{2}t^2\right)^2\,dt=...=\frac{1}{2800}$$

Let $P_2 \subset L^2([0,1])$ where $P_2=\text{span}\{1,t,t^2\}$. What you need to do is to compute $\text{proj}_{P_2}t^3$. You can do this by using the Gram-Schmidt process, how it works in $L^2$ it is not that different from how it works in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
